# Flutter - Get.changeTheme only works in ios simulator

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

this is a very strange behaviour.
I have four different themes.
In my controller

`class Controller extends GetxController { ..`

I set my current theme on event using my controller `final Controller c = Get.put(Controller());` like this:

```
void setAppMode(AppMode mode) async {
    appMode.value = mode;
    switch (appMode.value) {
      case AppMode.first:
        Get.changeTheme(firstTheme);
        break;
      case AppMode.second:
        Get.changeTheme(secondTheme);
        break;
      case AppMode.third:
        Get.changeTheme(thirdTheme);
        break;
      default:
        Get.changeTheme(firstTheme);
        break;
    }
  }
```

this actually works on ios simulator but it doesnt on chrome and macos.

Before implementing GetX I did implement a provider approach and it simply worked.
I switched to getx and I'm almost sure it has worked for a period on all of the platforms, then stopped.

I cannot actually find a commit after the switch where getx succedes in changing the theme (even if, again, I'm pretty sure it was working).

Another sign that something weird is on is that my logo image (that is being changed along with the theme) does update in ios simulator even if not wrapped by Obx, while in macos and chrome it needs to be wrapped (so practically speaking this code

```
Center(
       child: Image.asset(
            c.getLogoPath(),
       ),
),
```

is enough to make ios simulator update the logo image on event, while in chrome or macos I need this

```
Center(
       child: Obx(() => Image.asset(
             c.getLogoPath(),
       )),
),
```

and even in this case I'm pretty sure it worked without Obx wrap immediately after switching from provider towards GetX. And I'm also sure I've quit and rebuilt the runtime).

May there be any "caching" issue in the runtime?
what's going on? My flutter knowledge doesn't let me understand where the issue could hide.

By the way is quite clear to me that something does not behave like it should.

any hint?

**UPDATE**
this seems to be related to a bug:
https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/issues/1878

Answer (score 0):

this is not a solution but a workaround:
wrapping GetMaterialApp into Multiprovider I can sort of hybridise the approach switching on platform like following:

```
import 'dart:io';
...
class Controller extends GetxController {
...
final themeProvider = Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(Get.context!);//this actually makes the trick
...
void setAppMode(AppMode mode) {
...
changeTheme(themeBasedOnReceivedMode);
}
...
void changeTheme(ThemeData theme) {
    if (Platform.isAndroid || Platform.isIOS) {
      // Code for  Android and iOS
      print('ios/android');
      Get.changeTheme(theme);
    } else {
      // Code for other platforms
      print('macos/windows/linux');
      themeProvider.themeData = theme;
    }
  }
```

while the app builder would be something like this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => ThemeProvider()),
        ],
        child: Consumer<ThemeProvider>(
            builder: (context, themeProvider, child) => GetMaterialApp(
                  title: 'MyApp',
                  theme: themeProvider.themeData,
                  home: const SafeArea(child: AppWrapper()),
                )));
  }
```